# IBM AIX: How do I set up SSH X forwarding on an unprivileged user with no home?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, aix

Long story short: I have an AIX server where my user is unprivileged and has no home directory, and it is not easy to fix this because OS-level management of this server is outside of my jurisdiction.

I need to be able to do X over SSH on that server in order to run IBM Cognos Configuration, which is graphical only. I can't set my `XAUTHORITY` variable on my login profile because I don't have a profile, and since OS configuration is outside of my jurisdiction I don't think I'm allowed to globally set `XAUTHORITY` for all users, and doing so would require sorting through red tape and taking at least an hour working with the people in charge of the OS configuration. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change environment variables from the CLI:

```
 (Xauthority=.... ssh -Y me@myserver )
```

This spawns a shell in which the environment variable has a special value, but just for this subshell.